# bash script produces different output than when commands run in bash prompt

Tags: bash, shell-script

There is a script:

```
#!/bin/bash

s='1 2,   3   4,'
s0="$(echo ${s//,/ }|tr -s ' ')"
echo "s0: $s0"
d="'${s0//+([[:space:]])/"' '"}'"
echo "d: $d"
```

When I run this script output is:

```
$ ./test.sh
s0: 1 2 3 4
d: '1 2 3 4'
```

When I run the commands one by one in bash prompt, the `$d` variable is displayed properly:

```
$ s='1 2,   3   4,'
$ s0="$(echo ${s//,/ }|tr -s ' ')"
$ echo "s0: $s0"
s0: 1 2 3 4
$ d="'${s0//+([[:space:]])/"' '"}'"
$ echo "d: $d"
d: '1' '2' '3' '4'
$
```

Commands are run in bash:

```
$ type bash
bash is /bin/bash
$ echo $0
-bash
```

Why the `$d` during script run is set to `'1 2 3 4'` and not as expected `'1' '2' '3' '4'` ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Extended globs like `+(...)` aren't enabled in Bash by default, you'll need to explicitly use `shopt -s extglob` in the script to enable them.

Your interactive shell probably has `extglob` enabled (in some startup file), so the substitution command works as expected when you try it on the command line. But in the script, most startup files are not read, `extglob` is left disabled, and the plus and parentheses are taken as literal characters. The character class works the same in both, so something like `+( )` would match the pattern when `extglob` is off.

Here, the pattern doesn't match anything, there's no replacement and the only change you get in `d` are the single quotes you add around the `${s0//...}` expansion.